# Trying to find a very specific matrix, not sure how to start

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm trying to find a $6\times k$ binary matrix over $\mathbb R$ such that

1. Each row contains $t$ ones and rest enteries are zeroes.
2. Sum of any $5$ rows contains atleast $2t$ non zeroes.
3. Sum of any $4$ rows contains atmost $2t-1$ non zeros.

While a direct solution is acceptable, I'm looking for the method on how to find, prefereably, expressing it in linear algebraic terms somehow and then solving it

Comment: What information do you have about $k$ and $t$?(Except that they are natural and $2t\leq k$).

Comment: @Martund They were supposed to be arbitary, though the smaller the better. But I realized a serious fault in the technique that required this matrix, so it's not really useful now I guess